# application builds and compile with no error but showing error in the console in Angular?

Tags: angular

Showing this in the console of browser and app is not starting.

```
vendor.0f158aa391ad3634262e.bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
at Object.oxwE (vendor.0f158aa391ad3634262e.bundle.js:1)
at n (inline.168376d4e7af1a88c1cf.bundle.js:1)
at Object.+nms (vendor.0f158aa391ad3634262e.bundle.js:1)
at n (inline.168376d4e7af1a88c1cf.bundle.js:1)
at Object.cDNt (main.7e97085be0c43ae6de55.bundle.js:1)
at n (inline.168376d4e7af1a88c1cf.bundle.js:1)
at Object.0 (main.7e97085be0c43ae6de55.bundle.js:1)
at n (inline.168376d4e7af1a88c1cf.bundle.js:1)
at window.webpackJsonp (inline.168376d4e7af1a88c1cf.bundle.js:1)
at main.7e97085be0c43ae6de55.bundle.js:1
```

Comment: are u using angular-cli ? If yes pls post the version of angular-cli and angular.

Comment: "@angular/cli": "^1.1.1" & angular 4

Comment: u can try using the latest `1.4.9` version of `angular-cli`

Comment: Tried. Not working.